# Someone or something tried to login to my Gmail using IP address of my shared hosting

Tags: ip, shared-hosting, gmail

My Gmail told me someone tried to login with the **correct** password. But Gmail blocked it because the IP address used is different from my IP address. When I looked up the IP address that tried to login to my Gmail, it was the IP address of my shared hosting.
How is this possible? I don't remember connecting to my shared hosting or my website or my WordPress plugin with my Gmail.

Comment: Do a search in your files for 'gmail' to check if you have any script that may do that. If not, contact your hosting. They should have logs, or they can at least check the other users' files.

Comment: You can also go to https://myaccount.google.com From there you can review "Devices" under "Recent Activity". Also, check under "Account Permissions" for "Connected apps and services".